# How to write a image file like bitmap into a specific file path?

Tags: android, image, file, bitmap

I want to make an attachment function that allow the users to take a photo or select image from the gallery, then it shows at the attachment list view.

Then, when a user has chose his image, the result is whether a `FileSchemeUri` or `ContentSchemeUri`. So I tried to lower the bitmap's size and get the file path for click to view the image / set the icon in the attachmnet list view by using this function to get the outputFilePath:

```
    private File uriToFile(Uri uri, File sdImageMainDirectory) throws IOException{

    /*InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);*/

    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
    OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);

    int bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    int maxSize = 640;

    float bitmapRatio = (float) bitmapWidth / (float) bitmapHeight;

    if(bitmapRatio > 0){
        bitmapWidth = maxSize;
        bitmapHeight = (int) (bitmapWidth / bitmapRatio);
    }
    else{
        bitmapHeight = maxSize;
        bitmapWidth = (int) (bitmapHeight * bitmapRatio);
    }
    bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, true);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
   File outputFile = new File(String.valueOf(stream));
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
    return outputFile;
}
```

What I was trying to do is to write the bitmap into the specific path called `sdImageMainDirectory`. It failed since the outputFile's value is somekind of thing like this: `java.IO.FileOutputStream@438571`. And I took a look at my directory folder, those image became 0kb images(broken). I would like to ask how to write a bitmap into those directory? Please help.

Debug:

[image: When I create the scaledBitmap,]

[image: the bitmap contains things instead of null, and I can view the bitmap fine]

Comment: This line `File outputFile = new File(String.valueOf(stream));` is useless, you can delete it. However you code looks fine for writting the bitmap to the file. Are you sure your bitmap is good ? Can you add some debug logs to assert that the bitmap is not null and his size is not 0x0 ?

Comment: While I debug I can still view my Bitmap normally, but when I open the file from my phone, it was a 0kb image

Comment: What did you mean "when you debug" ? Please add some line like `Log.e("TOTO", "bitmap size = " + bitmap.getHeight() + " * " + bitmap.getWidth());`. I just want to be sure, that this line `Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);` actually produce the desired bitmap.

Comment: @sonic Image updated please have a look, thanks

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk What is the value of `sdImageMainDirectory`?

Comment: @EricB. /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/eLeaveAttachmentFolder/Screenshot_17122015_174544.jpg


      The filename I generate it by getInstance().getTime();

Comment: What does `bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);` return? `true` or `false`?

Comment: @JohnnyCheuk what did return `bitmap.compress` ? It should return `true` if it sucessfull.

Comment: One thing I forgot to tell is sometimes it's not 0kb but compress success, but just 1 out of 10 times it = happens

Answer (score 0):

Here's my choosing image method as well, please have a look:

```
  private void imageChooserDialog() {

    //region Create folder 'eLeaveAttachmentFolder'
    // Define a file name "root", which is a path of the user's phone's image directory, and create a file called "eLeaveAttachmentFolder"
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + File.separator + "eLeaveAttachmentFolder" + File.separator);

    // In the file object "root" (path), if the folder eLeaveAttachmentFolder is not exist, create one.
    root.mkdirs();
    //endregion

    //region Define where the result should save at
    // Define a string name claimfilename, which is used to store an image's name while it's created/selected.
    final String claimfilename = getUniqueImageFilenameForFilename();

    // Define a file name sdImageMainDirectory which is exactly the image's path (e.g. emulated\0\Pictures\eLeaveAttachmentFolder\Screenshot_08122015_160952.jpg)
    sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, claimfilename);
    //endregion


    // Assign the path 'sdImageMainDirectory' to the outputFileUri(Image in uri format)
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    //Camera

    // Create an arraylist to save types of intent (camera or gallery)
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();

    // Create the intent of camera
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // PackageManager manages uri installing and uninstalling
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    // ?? What is ResolveInfo?  packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0) ??
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);

    // "res" is to get all objects from the array "listCam"
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {

        // ?? ????
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;

        // Create the intent for saving the captureIntent
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);

        //
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);

        // Bundle the outputFileUri to onActivityResult
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

        // Set the quality of the image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        // Add the whole camera properties into one intent called cameraIntents
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));


    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE); // Activity to pop up the dialog, bundle the selectedImage Data to show at the onActivityResult
}
//endregion

//region onActivityResult
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();


            //Camera
            if (selectedImageUri == null) {
                //selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
             try{uriToFile(outputFileUri, sdImageMainDirectory);}
             catch(IOException e){}
            }

            else {
                try{uriToFile(selectedImageUri, sdImageMainDirectory);}
                catch(IOException e){}
            }
            }

            try {imageOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory); }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}

            claimattachmentfilename = getUniqueImageFilenameForShowing();
            claimattachmentpathname = getUniqueImageFilenameForFilename();

             /*try{claimattachmentbitmap = UriToBitmap(claimattachmenturi);}
             catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
            catch(IOException e){}*/

            newAttachment = new AttachmentListResult();
            // newAttachment.setBitmap(claimattachmentbitmap);
            newAttachment.setDirectory(sdImageMainDirectory);
            newAttachment.setFilename(claimattachmentfilename);
        //    newAttachment.setPathname(claimattachmentpathname);
          //  newAttachment.setByteArray(claimattachmentbytearray);
            if (lastAdapter != null) {attachmentarray = lastAdapter.getAttachmentArray();}

            attachmentarray.add(newAttachment);

            listViewUpdate();
        }
    }



//endregion
```

Comment: I finally scope the problem out, it was this line
` try {imageOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory); }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}`
It create a blank file inside that folder, damn I'm so stupid.